# Add an item of my own type to a list in Haskell?

Tags: list, function, haskell, types

I need to add my own data type to a list which is in a function, here's my code:

```
type Car = (String, String, Int, String)

testDatabase :: [Car] 
testDatabase = [("Ford", "Petrol", 2006, "Sport")]

addNewCar :: Car 
addNewCar newCar = newCar:testDatabase
```

Here's the error I get:

```
ERROR file:.\template.hs:20 - Type error in explicitly typed binding
*** Term : addNewCar
*** Type : ([Char],[Char],Int,[Char]) -> [([Char],[Char],Int,[Char])]
*** Does not match : Car
```

(sorry its a rubbish explanation im just struggling a tad with Haskell). Thank you in advance!!

Ash!

Comment: ERROR file:.\template.hs:20 - Type error in explicitly typed binding
*** Term           : addNewCar
*** Type           : ([Char],[Char],Int,[Char]) -> [([Char],[Char],Int,[Char])]
*** Does not match : Car

Comment: This is the error i get :/ Please help! - Also ive updated the copy-paste issues, thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The inferred type of `addNewCar` is `([Char],[Char],Int,[Char]) -> [([Char],[Char],Int,[Char])`, which is the same as `Car -> [Car]`. This type says that `addNewCar` is a function which takes a car and returns a list of cars. This is exactly the type you want.

However your type signature says that `addNewCar` is simply a value of type `Car`. This is wrong and clashes with the inferred type. That's why you get the error. So to fix this, simply remove the type signature or change it to `addNewCar :: Car -> [Car]`.

Comment: i love you... THANK YOU SO MUCH!! :D

Answer (score 3):

You have a type error in your code. `addNewCar` is a function that takes a car and returns a list of cars, so it should have the type

```
addNewCar :: Car -> [Car]
```

You could also just remove the type signature, and the compiler will infer it automatically.